# send data from ajax to spring controller

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

```
        var form_data = {
            itemid: globalSourceItem.substr(globalSourceItem.indexOf("-") + 1),
            columnName: jqInputs[0].value,
            displayName: jqInputs[1].value,
            format: jqInputs[2].value,
            KBE: jqInputs[3].value,
            dgroup: jqInputs[4].value,
            dupkey: jqInputs[5].value ,
            measurement: jqInputs[6].value ,
            times: new Date().getTime()
        };
        // console.log(form_data);
        // console.log($("#tourl").html());
        $.ajax({
            url: $("#tourl").html(),
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: form_data,
            success: function(message) {
                var j_obj = $.parseJSON(message);
                // console.log(j_obj);return false;
                if (j_obj.hasOwnProperty('success')) {
                    toastr.info('Item updated successfully');
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        window.location.reload();
                    },1000); 
                } else {
                    toastr.info('There was a problem.');
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                toastr.info('There seems to be a network problem. Please try again in some time.');
            }
        });

    }
```

Hii friends , this code is working for php and i need to send the same data to the spring mvc through the ajax , can anyone please help me with the exact solution where to make changes as Iam struckup with the same doubt for like 2 weeks...

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing currently?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestController {   
    @RequestMapping(value = "url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView action(@RequestBody FormData formData) {
        ...
    }
}

public class FormData { 
   private String itemid;
   public String getItemid() {
       return itemid;
   }
   public void setItemid(String itemid) {
       this.itemid = itemid;
   }    
   //...
}
```

Try sth like this. You should be able to map JSON Object to Java Object.

Maybe you could use annotation @ResponseBody and convert JSONObject to String:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String ajax(@RequestBody ListDataDefinition listDataDefinition) { 
    System.out.println("id="+listDataDefinition.getItemid()); 
    int i=SchemaDAOI.updateldd(listDataDefinition); 
    String message="success"; 
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); 
    try { 
        obj.put("success", "success"); 
    } 
    catch (JSONException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    if(i==1){ 
        System.out.println("success"); 
    } 
    else{ 
        System.out.println("failure"); 
    } 
    return obj.toString(); 
    } 
}
```

If you send String to View as ResponseBody and set produces as JSON it should be treated as pure JSON RQ.

Comment: Hey,thanks chmielu, it is working ,I am able to retrieve data at the server side but iam getting the error status as "There seems to be a network problem. Please try again in some time." I think i am not returning a json object from spring controller , can u please help me, my latest code is

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/ajax", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public JSONObject ajax(@RequestBody ListDataDefinition listDataDefinition)
 {
  
  System.out.println("id="+listDataDefinition.getItemid());
  int i=SchemaDAOI.updateldd(listDataDefinition);
  String message="success";
  
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
  try {
   obj.put("success", "success");
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  if(i==1){
   System.out.println("success");
  }
  else{
   System.out.println("failure");
  }
  return obj;
 }
}